# when I try to build on codeblocks and I don't understand why

Tags: c++, codeblocks

I used to use dev c++ but now I decided to switch over to codeblocks. dev c++ worked normally but when I try to build on codeblocks nothing happens. I typed out some code compiled it and build it but when I tried to run it a message popped up saying I haven't build it yet and if I would like to build it now. when I clicked yes nothing happend and when I clicked no it would run but not work normally. some youtube videos recommended going to settings then compiler, selecting GNU GCC compiler, going to Toolchain executables and cliicking auto detect. in my case when I clicked auto detect a message saying could not auto-detect installation path of "GNU GCC Compiler". what should I do to fix these errors

Comment: Do you have GCC installed? If yes, give CB the path manually. If not, [read this installation guide](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30069830/2752075).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat no I don't Ill read it.

Comment: Ok. It might still not auto-detect after the installation, which is ok. You can specify the path manually.

Answer (score 0):

install `GCC` then add its path to environment variable in `path` then click `auto-detect` again
if you're on windows

> type `environment variables` in search box
> click `environment variables` button in the dialog
> in `System Variables` group double-click `path`(add one if missing)
> click `New` then `Browse` buttons, naviagete to `GCC` folder
> click `Ok` buttons to confirm, then back to `code::blocks` to `auto-detect`

or set the path to `GCC` manually in `Toolchain executables` tab